# Update with condition in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a list of `id` and `sort`:

```
ids = ['123', '456', '789', '901'];
sorts = [1, 3, 2, 4];
```

I want to update the order of each `id` in Django.
Here is the SQL and Django i have tried:

**SQL:**

```
UPDATE  "Blogs" 
SET     sort = CASE 
                     WHEN  id = '123' THEN 1
                     WHEN  id = '456' THEN 3
                     WHEN  id = '789' THEN 2
                     WHEN  id = '901' THEN 4
                END
WHERE   id IN (ids);
```

**Django:**

```
Blogs.objects.filter(
            id=ids
        ).update(
            sort=Case(
                When(id=123, then=1),
                When(id=456, then=3),
                When(id=789, then=2),
                When(id=901, then=4),
            )
        )
```

But problem is when ids have many elements I can not specific `id` and `then` in `When(id={id}, then={sort})`.
How can I optimize the update query in Django version.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which db you are using? sqlite3 or mysql?

Comment: @zhiqianghuang I am using postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't explicitly provide the functionality you need here. You have already tried it using `CASE, WHEN` syntax and it would become unmanageable as the number of ids increase.

One solution that I can think of is that you create a temporary table with just `(id, sort)` column and join on that to update your `Blog` table.

Here is how you can do this:

1. Create a temporary table from `Blog` table using `id` and `sort` columns:

   ```
   from django.db import connection

   cursor = connection.cursor()
   blog_tbl_name = Blog._meta.db_table
   temp_tbl_name = "tmp_{}".format(blog_tbl_name)
   sql = (
        "CREATE TEMP TABLE {temp_tbl_name} AS "
        "SELECT id, sort FROM {blog_tbl_name} LIMIT 0;"
        .format(
            temp_tbl_name=temp_tbl_name,
            blog_tbl_name=blog_tbl_name
        )
   )

   cursor.execute(sql)
   ```
2. Now, insert the `(id, sort)` values into this temp table:

   ```
   ids = ['123', '456', '789', '901'];
   sorts = [1, 3, 2, 4];

   insert_sql = (
       "INSERT INTO {temp_tbl_name} (id, sort) VALUES (%s, %s);"
       .format(temp_tbl_name=temp_tbl_name)
   )

   # zip these two together and insert
   cursor.executemany(insert_sql, zip(ids, sorts))
   ```
3. Now, the last part where you update the `Blog` table by joining ids in the temp table:

   ```
   update_sql = (
       "UPDATE {blog_tbl_name} blog_tbl "
       "SET sort=tmp_tbl.sort "
       "FROM {temp_tbl_name} tmp_tbl "
       "WHERE blog_tbl.id = tmp_tbl.id;"
       .format(
            temp_tbl_name=temp_tbl_name,
            blog_tbl_name=blog_tbl_name
       )
   )

   cursor.execute(update_sql)
   ```

What is important to note here that this whole process requires only three queries and is manageable and efficient.